# Autowire Spring Bean based on boolean variable

Tags: java, spring

I want to configure the spring beans in such a way that depending on the value of a boolean variable, one of the two available connection bean gets autowired in the code.

Below is the initialization of the boolean variable:

```
//This is overridden as false from the properties file on the server.
@Value(value = "${my.property.connectionOne:true}") 
private boolean connectionOne;
```

I have defined the Bean in such a way:

```
@Bean(name = "specificConnection")
public Destination getSpecificConnection() throws Exception {
    if (connectionOne) { //boolean variable
        return new ConnectionOne("DB");
    }
    else {
        return new ConnectionTwo("XML");
    }
}
```

where `ConnectionOne` and `ConnectionTwo` both implement `Destination`

And I am using the bean in the desired class as:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "specificConnection")
private Destination specificConnection;
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. It keeps returning `ConnectionOne` only even if I change the value of the boolean variable to false.

I am using Spring version 4.2.0 and Wildfly Server.

Please let me know if any further clarification is required.

Comment: Show where connectionOne is initialized

Comment: Are you sure connectionOne boolean is false?

Comment: Where connectionOne variable is defined and where you change it value

Comment: yes @Betlista, the property is overridden from the server properties file.

@АлмасАбдразак please see below 
//This is overridden from the properties file on the server.

`@Value(value = "${my.property.connectionOne:true}") 

private boolean connectionOne;`

Comment: @АлмасАбдразак Edited my original code to show the declaration, since the comment was not getting formatted correctly.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to configure the spring beans in such a way that depending on
>   the value of a boolean variable

The boolean variable has to be valued before the initialization of the `specificConnection` bean by Spring.
So what you should probably do is using a value expression.

```
@Value("${isConnectionOne}") // looks the value in the available placeholder
private boolean isConnectionOne;

@Bean(name = "specificConnection")
public Destination getSpecificConnection() throws Exception {
    if (connectionOne) { //boolean variable
        return new ConnectionOne("DB");
    }
    else {
        return new ConnectionTwo("XML");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would to it your way. Another alternative to this is the beanfactory concept. Spring gives many ways!

Comment: Right. If it is not too complex and makes sense you could show that :)

Comment: @davidxxx I am doing it this way only. But still it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example for spring profiles! Have a look on this link:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

In Spring, you can define different profiles your program will run in. Based on settings you define in your application.properties your program will use different beans of these profiles. :)

I hope that could help you!

Greethings

Noixes

Comment: is this only for Spring Boot application or will it work for normal spring application? Also, using profiling I guess I can wire different beans altogether depending on my profile but can I use the same method to return different results?

Comment: @phoenixSid I think you need spring boot, but it should be available for you. davidxxx should have the right answer for bean-creation with a boolean. But you should provide a way to change this variable during runtime. :)

Comment: Yes we are planning to move gradually to a spring-boot architecture, but until then its normal spring app running in wildfly.